# How to make javascript custom async function without using I/O?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I have below JS code and I want to make it asynchronous behavior but it is not behave like async. I have passes a callback as well to behave like callback.
Please suggest how to make async without using settimeout function or any http request.

```
console.log('1');
cc('', function(d){ 
    console.log(d); 
});
console.log('3');

function cc(err, callback){
    for(var i=1; i<=900000000; i++){}

    console.log(i);
    if(typeof callback == 'function'){
        callback('2.5');
    }
}
```

//output comming

```
1
900000001
2.5
3
```

//Expected

```
1
3
900000001
2.5
```

Comment: A callback is just a function reference passed as a parameter. Using a callback doesn't make your code asynchronous. Why do you need your code to be asynchronous if you don't perform any asynchronous operation?

Comment: Actually I want to know the ways how to make js code async.
Really appreciate if you can help.

Comment: So you basically want to convert a synchronous blocking operation to an asynchronous one? In the browser? Then use Web Workers.

Comment: yes @Razem You are right.

Answer (score 2):

The only time an async function is useful is when the main thread has to *wait* for something.

Your example has a loop (which does nothing practical but takes a lot of work to do it … note that "working" is not "waiting").

You can't really make it async (because the work still needs to be done, and that will keep the JS engine busy running it).

The closest you could come would be to farm the work off to something other than the main JS thread (e.g. (and which of these options are available depends on the JS environment you are running your code in: JS has no *native* way of doing this) you could run it on a different server and communicate with it via ZeroMQ or HTTP, or you could use a Web Worker) and then have an asynchronous function which sends a request to that "something other" and resolves when it gets a response.

Comment: How this works,   
console.log('start');
setTimeout(function(){ console.log( 'inside' )}, 2000);
console.log('end');

Comment: @AmitSingh — See the first sentence of this answer. `setTimeout` is waiting for something (2 seconds to pass in this case).